# How can I add multiple parameters to message.content?

Tags: node.js, cmd, discord, discord.js

Need some help with my code. I started coding my first Discord bot today using Node.JS and the Discord.JS library, and others soon. I am currently using a YouTube video to guide me through Node.JS. Here's my question.

Here is my current code.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on('message', (message) => {

    if(message.content == 'ping') {
        message.reply('pong');
    }

    if(message.content == 'xd') {
        message.reply('smh');
    }

});
```

This code works fine. If you go over to the second `message.content`, it has `'xd'` written inside it. When I write the word xd in my Discord server, the bot will return `smh`. The problem with this is that the bot will only return `smh` when the capitalization is exactly like it is in `xd`, but I want it to work for all capitalization.

Like this.

```
    if(message.content == 'xd', 'xD', 'XD', 'Xd',) {
        message.reply('pong');
}
```

Obviously, the above code doesn't work, but is there any easy way to do this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I answer the question, make sure hide your bot's token when sharing your source code because then people can use your bot to do some harmful stuff if it has the right permissions.

**Okay so the answer:**

At the very beginning, declare a variable called msg or something that stores `message.content.toLowerCase();`. So no matter how the person types it, it will always be lower case.

Be aware that it will only work if message.content is "xd" only so if a person type "xD something", this wouldn't work.

**Additional stuff to your code:**

If you want to check if a person used a certain prefix to signify a command, you can check if `message.content.startsWith("prefix");` - this will return true or false.

It's always good to break down the content of the message into separate variables allowing you to easily do what you wanna do with the message, for example, a command and args variable *(convert `message.content` into an array first)*.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I had my token there. It has been removed and reset. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can call `.toLowerCase()` on `message.content` to transform it to all lower case:

```
if (message.content.toLowerCase() == 'xd') {
  message.reply('pong');
}
```

This way the message's casing is practically ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You need to lowercase the message.content using method toLowerCase() method then compare it with "xd string using === operator

ex:

```
if(message.content && message.content.toLowerCase() === 'xd') {
    message.reply("smh");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 other main ways to allow for multiple parameters besides the  `toLowerCase()` function.

The first way would be to use the `||` operator or the `or` operator. This method allows for you to check for completely different words while being able to have the same outcome. For example:

```
if (message.content == "xd" || message.content == "xD" || message.content == "XD") { 
     message.reply("Why would you do that");
}
```

The second way would be to use regular expressions like regexes. Regexes check for words inside strings by using the `.test()` method. For example:

```
let myRegex = /xd/i;
if (myRegex.test(message.content)) { //We are assuming that message.content = "XD"
   message.reply("smh");
}
```

This method works because the regex checks whether the word is equal to the regex it is assigned to. The `i` after the `/xd/` means that it doesn't care about the casing so this is a shorter way to check for certain words without caring about letter case.

Answer (score 0):

use toLowerCase on the content and then test it

```js
if(message.content.toLowerCase() === 'xd') {
   message.reply('pong');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way todo this is have aliases...

```
//defined early on.
let commands = [
    {
        aliases:["xd","lol",":smile:"],
        run:function(msg){
            msg.send(`pong`);
        }
    },
    {
        aliases:[":("],
        run:function(msg){
            msg.send(`why the long face?`);
        }
    }
]
//later
client.on(`message`,function(msg){
    for(let i =0;i<commands;i++){
        if(commands[i].includes(msg.content.toLowerCase())){
            commands[i].run();
        }
    }
});
```

`string.toLowerCase` as answered above doesn't always work when you want multiple things to run the same command.
The code above allows aliases for every commands

Answer (score -1):

you can use something like || to have multiple parameters.
In your case it would look like this

```
if(message.content == 'xd' || 'Xd' || 'xD' || 'XD') {
    message.reply('idk');
}
```

But in your case (because it is always the two same letters in the same order) you can simply add .toLowercase() and then the message will be treated as if it had only lowercase letters and you won't have to worry.

example:

```
if(message.content.toLowercase() === 'xd') {
    message.reply('idk');
}
```

However there's also a third option to have multiple parameters, you can simply use a constant (const)

example:

```
const 1 = [ "xd" , "lmao" , "lmfao" ]

if(message.content == 1) {
    message.reply('idk');
}
```

You can change "1" for info

Have a nice day :)

oh and thanks to the moderator that corrected me and sorry for my mistake.

Comment: Of course it's useless, it won't work if `message.content` is `"ping"`, only when it's `"Ping"`. The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32258339)